# Compare two columns one of them with sum function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table
table1
table1 contains columns (id,item,quantity1) id PK

[image: table1]

The other table
table2
table2 contains columns (no,quantity2,id) id FK

[image: table2]

I want to compare quantity1 from table1 with sum(quantity2) from table2(find the same result in quantity1 and quantity2

I mean I want to give me result of quantity1 with the same result in quantity2

```
quantity1     quantity2
    20           20
     5           5
```

I try this but it doesn't work(error in syntax)

```
SELECT       table1.id, table1.quantity1,
              table1.item, SUM(table2.quantity2) AS Expr1
FROM            table1 INNER JOIN
                table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
                where table1.quantity1 = Expr1
                GROUP BY table1.id, table1.quantity1, table1.item
```

Comment: (1) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? (2) Define "does not work" (3) Are there several rows in table2 for a given id? (4) Sample data, current and desired results, provided as tabular text, would improve your question.

Comment: What results do you want?  What does "compare" mean?

Comment: Don't put a filter on where ```quantity=quantity```.  Just select both quantities and maybe do a calculation to display the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can go step by step approach for more clarity. You can use CTE and then join.

```sql
;WITH CTE_Table2 AS
(
SELECT id,Sum(quantity2) as quantity_sum
FROM Table2
GROUP BY id
)
SELECT t1.id, t1.quantity1, t1.item, t2.quantity_sum
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN CTE_Table2 AS t2
ON t2.id = t1.id
AND t2.quantity_sum = t1.quantity1
```

Answer (score 0):

To compare aggregates use HAVING:

```
SELECT table1.id
      ,table1.quantity1
      ,table1.item
      ,SUM(table2.quantity2) AS Expr1
FROM  table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id, table1.quantity1, table1.item
HAVING SUM(table2.quantity2)=table1.quantity1
```